# Ruby on Rails: test db is persisting data. I'm using Cucumber, how do I clear the DB after each scenario?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, cucumber

Preferably, I'd like something to go in this method defined in support/env.rb

```
After do |scenario|
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add these three lines at the bottom of your env.rb

# http://github.com/bmabey/database_cleaner for more info.
require 'database_cleaner' 
DatabaseCleaner.strategy = :truncation